# How to replicate an SQL group by Query with Stats (e.g count()) and get Arbitrary Number of Values as Sample in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replicate this SQL query in python data input is a dataframe. * would like to do so by using pandas.

```
select field_A, count(*) cnt, arbitrary(field_B)
  from table1
 group by field_A
```

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

a simple python solution would be to use `pandas` and `pandasql`

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0, '10/11/12'], [1, '12/11/10']],
                  columns=['int_column', 'date_column'])

ps.sqldf("""select * from df""")
```

#### output

```
int_column  date_column
0   0   10/11/12
1   1   12/11/10
```

Comment: Thanks fo the tip!! Will be nice to see how it can be done in python too...

Comment: not to be pedantic but this is python. the most common python packages for working with tables and sql are pandas and sqlalchemy. which tools you use depend on where the data is (local vs db), the size, and what kind of transformation you're trying to do. if you'd like a more specific answer I would add more information to your post

Comment: sqlite does not include the arbitrary or similar function on their built-in functions. 
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html.

Comment: so are you asking for a way to interact with a sqlite db using python?

Comment: no @will-wright-eng the question, maybe badly made was using pandas how can I get an arbitrary value from a groupby. your suggestion is using sqlalchemy and the version of SQL is sqlite. sqlite does not have and arbitrary function. Although I could use a max or min funcion ot get a value sometimes I woud likce to get an array of values as examples.

Comment: I would suggest modifying your question to satisfy SO guidelines around [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)